# Admin inline without foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am creating a blog and I am a beginner in Django. I have three models Slug, Post, Category.

```
class Slug(models.Model):
    slugable_type = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    slugable_id = models.IntegerField()
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=127)


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Post(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField()
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Now In Slug model `slugable_type` will contain the model name (Post or Category) and `slugable_id` is the id of that model object. 
In this way, I want to set up a polymorphic relation (just like I do in Laravel) between Slug, Post and Category Model. Where each object of Category and Post model will have exactly one corresponding Slug Object.

Now I want to create a slug while creating a post or category. But don't know how to register these three model in Django administration.

As to have an admin inline there must be a Foreign key defined which is not possible in my case.

**Updated**

The reason I want to do this is that there won't be any common slug for Category or Post. Eg:
consider a post which has a slug 'unique-slug-1'. So there can not be a category with slug 'unique-slug-1'.

Answer (score 0):

You should setup Generic foreign key for this purpose,  it is the same as polymorphic relation in Lavarel as far as I am concerned. And there is GenericAdminInline for admin panel integration. But actually it is concerned as bad design,  so better think how you can redesign your models to use plain ForeignKey. I would suggest just to create two different Slug models,  or move the slug field directly into Post and Category model.  Also,  you can use inheritance: define Slug model with slug field and inherit Post and Category from it. If you don't need to query Slug model,  add abstract=True to the Slug.Meta