# Django Admin Inline without foreign key

Tags: python, django

I saw many question and answers but i could not find certain answer.

[Admin inline without foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50089007/admin-inline-without-foreign-key)

[Django admin inline display but foreign key has opposite relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15339809/django-admin-inline-display-but-foreign-key-has-opposite-relation)

So can i iterate model fields without relation to other models

```
class CommentTabularInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Comment
    fields = ('content_type', 'text')
    extra = 1

class CommentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [CommentTabularInline]

admin.site.register(Comment, CommentAdmin)
```

model

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, CASCADE, 'user_comment')
    text = models.TextField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I tried to do this, but i am getting error

> : (admin.E202)
>   'main.Comment' has no ForeignKey to 'main.Comment'

Comment: This question is unclear. Why are you trying to get a model inline with itself?